# BigCommerce jspm install error and bitbucket timeout

Tags: windows, npm, bigcommerce, jspm

I have a case open with BigCommerce on this issue and they have instructed me to post here for assistance.  Case# 02715192.  I am running Windows 10.

I have been successful in setting up Stencil CLI with the base Cornerstone template.  All of the dependencies installed successfully and I had my site loaded up on port 3000 and javascript was working and is working still when I load up.  My problem is related to using my purchased Showroom theme from the marketplace.  Since the Cornerstone still loads and works successfully, I am at a loss for why I cannot get Showroom to function with javascript.  They are installed in different sub-directories as instructed.

When I run stencil init, I get an error loading js/app in the assets folder (see screenshot).  I imagine this is why javascript is not running on the Showroom template within my local port.  I found the troubleshooting guide and it tells me to install a fresh copy of the theme and run npm install && jspm install.  Well, npm install is fine, but jspm install times out and I get errors (see additional screenshot).  It seems this is the source of my woes, but have been unable to find a fix.

stencil init error:

[image: stencil init error]

jspm install error:

[image: jspm install error]

Comment: I have poured over all of the documentation and troubleshooting guides.  I have started fresh multiple times and while the base template loads fine, a purchased marketplace theme is still not fully working within Stencil CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like its an issue with JSPM-git [https://github.com/Orbs/jspm-git/issues/52].

Try changing line 50 of git.js from `versionArr = stdout.match(/\d.\d.\d/);` to `versionArr = stdout.match(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+/);`

Comment: Appreciate any and all help.  But, I am not sure where I am supposed to edit line 50.  I don't think I have access to the necessary code to change that.

Comment: After running `npm install` inside of the showroom folder you should see a folder called node_modules. The git.js file we are looking for is located at `./node_modules/jspm-git/`.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much for your help.  Seems like magic almost.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this exact same issue, but I think I've found a fix:

Follow the doc here:
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/downloading-and-customizing-marketplace-themes

When you get to the part titled "Installing jspm-git" run "npm install jspm-git --save"

This seemed to resolve the install errors for us.  We also enabled ssh for bitbucket, but from my testing I don't believe that had any impact on the resolution.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't work for me.  BC Engineer pointed me to Pixel Union's documentation here: https://www.pixelunion.net/support/setting-bigcommerce-theme-development/.  I've followed these steps as well and still end up with the errors.  The errors pop-up after executing 'jspm install.'

Even with these errors, it still lets me load up Stencil.  It gives me the same errors upon Stencil init and when loading the site in the browser, javascript is still not working.  This makes it hard to develop.